# What flavor of Defender do I get on my computer

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-defender

I see many terminologies when it comes to Windows Defender. For example, [this document](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/microsoft-defender-antivirus/microsoft-defender-antivirus-compatibility) has references to `Microsoft Defender Antivirus` and also `Microsoft Defender for Endpoint`.  Also, I read a few places about `Microsoft Defender Advanced Thread Protection`. All of this left me confused. I know that my Windows 10 computer comes with Defender pre-installed. How is what I have on my device relates to all of these different flavors.

Answer (score 0):

> I know that my Windows 10 computer comes with Defender pre-installed.

With "Windows Defender", to be exact.

> How is what I have on my device relates to all of these different flavors.

With the cool name "Defender". Almost like "Java" and "Javascript", "Defender" and "Defender ATP" do have nothingt commong except the name and "something with security".

Comment: So Windows 10 computer comes with Windows Defender and not Microsoft Defender for Endpoint? What's the difference between the two? Googling confuses me more :(

Comment: @BKS: Microsoft Defender for Endpoint is the enterprise product that has additional features and management capability/reporting.